# How to return array item views in an infinity loop in react native render?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, arraylist

suppose list.length is 5. I need to return the below view in an infinity loop. Not in a loop of 5. I want to go through the array one by one. when it is come to the index 4, it should pointed to the 0 index again. this process should be executed recursively.
in here, it will stop after coming to the last index of the array.
when "i" came to the last index of array, I tried to set "i=0", but it is not accessible. 
Is there any way to implement this scenario in javascript.

NB: I will paste some code snippet of my render method in my react native jsx file.
any comments are welcome.

```
return this.state.list
      .map((item, i) => {
        if (i === this.state.currentIndex) {
          return (
            <Animated.View
              {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}
              key={item.id}
              style={[
                this.rotateAndTranslate,
                { height: SCREEN_HEIGHT - 120, width: SCREEN_WIDTH, padding: 10, position: "absolute" }
              ]}
            >
              <Animated.View
                style={{
                  opacity: this.likeOpacity,
                  transform: [{ rotate: "-30deg" }],
                  position: "absolute",
                  top: 50,
                  left: 40,
                  zIndex: 1000
                }}
              >
              ....................more codes....................... 
              </Animated.View>

              <Image style={{ flex: 1, resizeMode: "contain", borderRadius: 20 }} source={{ uri: item.image }} />
            </Animated.View>
          );
        }else{
           return something;
        }

    }).reverse();
```

Comment: Looks like you want to loop an animation. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated#loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a functional component which reloads after 5 clicks..

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const Example = ({title}) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  
  const [compCount, setCompCount] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
    {<GetComp value={compCount}/>}
      <button onClick={() => {
        setCount(count+1);
        if(count % 5 ==0 && count != 0){
          setCompCount(compCount + 5)
        }
      }}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const GetComp = props => {
  return [1,2,3,4,5].map(e => <div> {e+props.value} </div>)
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example title="Example using Hooks:" />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifying `i` like that won't have any effect on the next iteration because it is an argument in the function passed to [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).  If you want to manipulate `i` like that, you should use a loop with `i` defined outside the scope of the loop's body.

Something like

```
let i = 0;
while (i < this.state.list.length) {
  if (something) {
    i++;
  } else {
    i = 0;
  }
}
```

It's a little difficult to understand exactly what it is you're trying to accomplish, but hopefully this helps clear up some of the confusion.

Comment: this logic is correct. but the problem is returning my array with this iterations. in map function I can return it as "return myArray.map();". What can I do when using this while and for loops?

Comment: You could push to an array you define outside the loop, then return the array

Comment: nothing to push there. Can you please check my example and edit your answer with return views of the array. it will be a big help. returning array inside the loop is not what I want here.